# GAE Python: Using filter and cursor with memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say you have a list of posts with 5 categories.
When you do memcache, how should you filter out the categories?

```
class Post(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    category = db.StringProperty()
    desc = db.StringProperty()
```

When you do caching:

```
key = "allpost"
post = Post.all().order('-created')
memcache.set(key, post)
```

I tried the use filter on cached object. And apparent it wouldn't work.

> cached_post.filter("category","one")

Is there any function you can do it?  Or do you just have to go through the pain to filter all the categories first before caching all the posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put named things in memcache and get them out again via their key as a single piece. It looks to me as if you are putting into memcache a incomplete query or model, rather then the **results** of a query which you could then *potentially* filter.

Take a look at NDB, much of the memcaching is done for you with that (not for queries however).

So you can filter on the data you get from memcache but there are no commands to do in-memcache filtering.

Have a look at the available functions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot I can just use python to filter out the items. However, I originally used cursor to do pagination. Simply use python would work too. Do you think it's better not to use cursor to paginate?

Comment: I'm afraid "it depends". Cursors are great, but don't forget cursors can "go out of date" as you use them so it really depends on your specific use case.